# Cordova on Android - use of cordova-plugin-datagram

Tags: javascript, cordova-plugins

I am new in developing Cordova apps for Android, and I have a problem with how to use the `cordova-plugin-datagram` plugin. I tried several mechanisms like import / require, nothing worked.
Feedback In Console:

> Uncaught Error: module cordova-plugin-datagram.datagram not found

I went through the following steps:

1. Working toolchain available (already built multiple apps)
2. Created Hello World app as a starting point
3. Added Android platform
4. `npm i cordova-plugin-dgram` to add the plugin
5. Added:
   `var datagram = cordova.require("cordova-plugin-datagram.datagram");` => This causes issues.

My simple code:

```js
// Wait for the deviceready event before using any of Cordova's device APIs.
// See https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#deviceready
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

var datagram = cordova.require("cordova-plugin-datagram.datagram");

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Cordova is now initialized. Have fun!

    console.log('Running cordova-' + cordova.platformId + '@' + cordova.version);
    document.getElementById('deviceready').classList.add('ready');
}
```

Could somebody give some help on how to use this?
Is there a need to add a link to the script in the HTML?
Thanks for reply, struggling now one day on this...

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. Also take the [tour].